# Can't match Postgres insert speed with SQLite3 in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite

I have a database with a single indexed UNIQUE text column, currently at 100m rows but it could go up to a billion. this is for doing millions of **contains** queries on the db so index is necessary for fast lookup.

The problem i'm having is imports have slowed down by a lot as the DB got bigger. I've tried a lot of ideas including stuff like this (reads roughly 100k lines from file and does batch insert):

```
lines = f.readlines(3355629)
while lines:
  c.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION')
  rows_modified += c.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO mydb (name) values (?)', map(lambda name: (name.strip().lower(),), lines)).rowcount
  c.execute('COMMIT')
  lines = f.readlines(3355629)
```

the above takes many minutes to insert 100k lines when the DB is at 100m rows.

I've imported to Postgres with a python script which can get 100k inserts on an indexed column in 2 seconds at 100m rows (using psycopg2.extras.execute_values).

I keep seeing claims that SQLite can easily handle terabytes of data, yet can't figure out how to get the data in. BTW I can't drop the index and recreate it because then id need additional code to make sure the data is unique, and you can't change a column to UNIQUE after creation. Multiple tables is an option for speed increase though it makes things more complex.

Comment: Why not just load the database from a file?  That is usually much faster.

Comment: loading via .mode csv and .import myfile via the SQLite shell is even slower than my code from what i could see.

Comment: Is it a `WITHOUT ROWID` table, or a normal one?

Comment: @Shawn no the table has rowids

Comment: For my understanding about the Postgres import, was the machine of the Postgres server the same of the machine running SQLite, or with comparable characteristics?

Comment: Is the cache_size of SQLite about equal to the shared_buffers size of PostgreSQL?  If not, then you are comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @jjanes postgres no. I switched SQLite cache_size for that session to both 125000 and -125000 to mimic Postgres at 128mb but got no significant change in speed per 100k lines imported.

Comment: @marco.m yes, both running on the same machine.

Comment: Not really an answer, but the SQLite forum has the SQLite developers themselves answering questions, you might have more luck there: https://sqlite.org/forum/about